# object recognition algorithm that can generate Bounding box along the object

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-recognition, background-foreground

I'm working on a dataset which contains biscuits and soaps in which most of the cases biscuits/soaps are rotated. For training images, I'm having a white background in the image, so I can generate a Bounding box along with the object by thresholding white colour. But in testing Background may be anything.

Bounding Box should look like green colour, not red colour in this image:[Bounding Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UA9q.png)

I mean Bounding Box along object means Green colour Bounding Box in the above image.

I have implemented YOLOV3 which generated the red colour type of Bounding Box.so I need an object recognizer algorithm which generates the Green colour type of Bounding Box

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but based on what I understand here's a possible answer. One way you can do is to do adaptive thresholding (OpenCV) and then findContours. Once you have filtered out the desired object you can do a minAreaRect on contour points (search for OpenCV minAreaRect example).

Here's a link which might be useful:

[Min Area Rect Example](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dcf/tutorial_js_contour_features.html)

Comment: Just to clarify this is not an object recognition algorithm (as the title of your question requires)..this is just segmentation mechanism.

Comment: sorry, @Knight Forked for asking a question in a wrong way. ok in terms of segmentation can adaptive thresholding extract foreground from an image independent of the background,bcz background may be anything.

Comment: Well, that's hard to say. A lot depends on the background. If your foreground is virtually indistinguishable to your background then you are out of luck. You might still want to try out adaptiveThreshold (or any other global/local thresholding - Otsu etc.) to see which one suits your needs best. Eventually you will have to put constraints on your thresholding and contour finding with the specific domain knowledge of the kind of images/data you will be dealing with.

Comment: I have implemented a haar-cascade classifier, but the problem with haar-cascade is: it is not producing Bounding boxes on rotated objects. (like it is not rotation invariant, if I train a haar-cascade with non-rotated images it is not producing Bounding boxes on rotated images).   Do you have a say on it??

Comment: @KnightForked: adaptive thresholding will completely failed. The background is as complex as the foreground. Without a template of what you are looking for, this task cannot be achieved.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: can u please elaborate is this task can be achieved or not by applying other algorithms ..

Comment: @vamsi: this is implicit in my previous comment: template matching.

Comment: @vamsi, were you able to use templates as suggested by Yves to achieve the results you were looking for? Do you have the sample images that you can share?